# maintain jquery event from one php page to another

Tags: php, jquery

I am having this situation:
- having a php page
- having a jQuery script that collapses a menu
- clicking on one of the collapsed elements to load another page by passing variable(s) in php

Problem:
- jQuery script reloads too and cancels my previous choice.

Here is an example. I click on "Menu", jQuery script acts on "collapser" but when I click on the "Fish" link (or other), I got the page displayed but the menu will not be shown as collapsed.

What I want to achieve:
- to keep the menu collapsed while moving from one page to another

here is a php code sample.

```
echo rightMenu();
function rightMenu(){

    $r  = '';

    $r .= '<ul id="collapser"><li>Menu<ul>';
    $r .= '<li><a href="main.php?show=page1">Fish</a></li>';
    $r .= '<li><a href="main.php?show=page2">Vegetables</a></li>';
    $r .= '<li><a href="main.php?show=page3">Meat</a></li></ul>';
    $r .= '</li></ul>';

    return $r;
};
```

Thank you,
Myriam

Comment: You will need a cookie, session variable or some other data that you can pass from page to page that will indicate the current status of the menu. Since each page is unaware of the other pages they need something to read from to be on the same page, so to speak.

Comment: As you expand and collapse, use Javascript to save the state of the collapsibles to a cookie, then on the page load, read the cookie and replicate the state. This isn't a job for the server so I wouldn't use the session or do any ajax.

Comment: take a look over https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: call javascript function after the page load - 

ur = location.href;
ur = ur.split("=");
ur = ur[1]  ---> this will give you page1 / page2 / page3

now add some ACTIVE class to your li having <a href > to the corresponding page.

Answer (score 1):

If you include `jQuery.cookie`, you can use a cookie to do it, which should be simpler:

```
$("#collapser").click(function () {
   //change to more appropriate value
   $.cookie('autocollapse', $(this).is(":visible"), {expires: 30});
});

//initial page load
if ($.cookie('autocollapse')) {
   $("#collapser").click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When collapse is clicked, you can send an ajax request that records a session variable of some sort that indicates collapse:

```
//Your collapser click function
//record hidden status in data
$("#collapser").click(function () {
   if ($(this).data('hidden')) {
      $(this).slideDown().data('hidden', false);
   }
   else {
      $(this).slideUp().data('hidden', true);
   }
   //record hidden (collapsed) status on the server
   $.post('/record-collapser-hide.php', {'hidden': $(this).data('hidden')});
});

//On initial page load, collapse if #autocollapse is in the DOM
//Added by PHP code below
if ($("#autocollapse").length) {
   $("#collapser").data('hidden', false).click();
}


//--- record-collapser-hide.php ---
session_start();
$_SESSION['collapsercollapsed'] = isset($_POST['hidden']) ? $_POST['hidden'] : 0;


//--- function rightMenu() ---
...
$r .= '</li></ul>';
if (isset($_SESSION['collapsercollapsed']) && $_SESSION['collapsercollapsed']) {
   $r .= "<span style='display: none' id='autocollapse'>&nbsp;</span>";
}
```

NOTE: This code will most likely not work as-is, but you should be able to follow the basic idea.

Comment: Thank you. I thought there was a simpler (straightforward) way do achieve this without using AJAX. I'll dig into your code.